# Reading Nested Groupnames from Active Directory using Users SAMAccountName

Tags: c#, active-directory-group

I need a function to recursively get all groups names a specified user (as function argument) is a member of. The Function header should look like this where `SAMAccountName` is the Username I want to get the groups from:

```
public List<string> GetUsersGroups(string SAMAccountName);
```

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your problem is active directory side knowledge, not c#.

Basically task is ldap action, but I'll give examples using adfind that is quick and handy tool to output ldap queries to csv file for example. Functions you have to create by yourself.

There are 2 functions you need:

Function 1, find DN from samaccountname:
adfind -dsq -f samaccountname=username

Function 2, find groups, including nested ones:
adfind -f "(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=USERDN,OU=USERS,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM)" samaccountname -list

Please find adfind syntax from joeware website:
http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/adfind/usage.htm

For nested groups, more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/f238d2b0-a1d7-48e8-8a60-542e7ccfa2e8/recursive-retrieval-of-all-ad-group-memberships-of-a-user?forum=ITCG